# What changes made to a computer connected to a domain network can be detected by the system administrator?

Tags: ssh-tunnel, windows-domain

My work PC (Windows 7 Enterprise) is connected to a domain network. I have the admin username and password so I can change all the settings. Obviously its behind a firewall or something. The network icon shows Internet access but cant open any websites. I don’t have much knowledge of how domains work so can someone please clarify the following:

- What are changes that I might do the computer (installing a application, changing network parameters, adding a device, installing drivers etc.) that can be detected by the system admin?
- To access the Internet I am planning to change the DNS servers of the PC to Google’s. Will this work or will be detected?
- I also came to know about SSH tunnelling. Will setting up a SSH tunnel be detected?

I was told it’s an admin PC. Does this mean it’s also the domain controller? Also we don’t have any IT guy/admin in our office. As its a bank, there’s a data center setup somewhere in other city which manages all the PCs.

Comment: Most of what you want to attempt is possibly illegal at worst, at best it's reprehensible just to attempt these things. Do you like porridge?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, issues specific to enterprise hardware, software, and networks are off topic.  Your question should be directed to your IT department.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you are in an office environment and the machines are remotely administered and you did not set them up, you should *always* assume that *everything* you do is going to be monitored *at all times*.

That said, you say this:

> I have the admin username and password so I can change all the
>   settings.

And then you say this:

> Also we don’t have any IT guy/admin in our office. As its a bank,
>   there’s a data center setup somewhere in other city which manages all
>   the PCs.

Why would you have any admin access to the PC? Were you given it or you sort of “found out” from a co-worker what the credentials are? If this is a legit bank, chances of you being caught are extremely high.

So past the technical specifics, is it worth it for you to do all of these things to potentially lose your job and possibly not be able to work at any bank again due to you “hacking” your work computer to browse the Internet?

Just do what everyone else does: Have their own, personal smartphone with a data plan and look at that when you are bored at work.

Comment: We have to perform some operations from time to time which requires having Admin access. I am in charge of those operations so the Admin username and password is given to me.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you're doing can be found out if an admin accesses your computer. If it's Windows 7 Enterprise it's not going to be domain controller of a bank and more than likely will have group policy settings that prevent you monkeying around without getting caught.

Answer (score 0):

*Don't touch anything without asking*

Quite literally, changing anything on the system might be illegal and/or affect the security of your workplace.

To put it bluntly its not *your* computer (in terms of ownership) nor *your* computer in terms of usage,and you may or may not end up taking down your entire workplace at once doing this.

> What are changes that I might do the computer (installing a
> application, changing network parameters, adding a device, installing
> drivers etc.) that can be detected by the system admin?

It depends. If your system is set up correctly, nearly everything could be. A *unplanned reboot* such as one a driver update would do would certainly be noticed.

Even if its not 'your' account you're using, a good cyber forensic practitioner (or even a mediocre one) can sniff out who it was. For that matter a *undergrad* cyberforensics student could work out 3-4 ways of doing this. And well, accidentally taking down a critical system in a bank will likely result in *expensive* teams of *experts* who'll be going through everything with a fine toothed comb.

> To access the Internet I am planning to change the DNS servers of the
> PC to Google’s. Will this work or will be detected?

If a computer cannot access the internet there's probably *a good reason* whether its due to a firewall blocking most of the internet, or forcing everything through a proxy. Its not just about DNS.

> I also came to know about SSH tunnelling. Will setting up a SSH tunnel
> be detected?

Lets get this straight. You want to poke an  entirely secure hole from a system that clearly seems to be well secured into an *insecure* system that's at best managed by yourself, and at worst, by some random third party. Does sound like a bad idea dosen't it?

> I was told it’s an admin PC.

It could be adminning anything from the DC to the access control system. I do wonder how everyone would feel if they accidentally got locked in at work, or lost access to their accounts.

> Does this mean it’s also the domain controller?

Or controls the secret nuclear reactor under your bank, that will melt down and kill us all. You tell me.

> Also we don’t have any IT guy/admin in our office.

Means they don't expect you to break things all that often. Or are cheap. Or both.

> As its a bank, there’s a data center setup somewhere in other city
> which manages all the PCs.

Excellent. If you break something they will need to *fly some poor IT guy in*. Economy class maybe. Someone *will* be mad at whoever broke everything.

> I have the admin username and password so I can change all the
> settings

Someone goofed. Unless you have a clear business need to need it, which I doubt, you might need to forget that password for your own good.

I'd second [Giacomo1968's answer which suggests the smartphone](https://superuser.com/a/991463/167207), and [Kilisi's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/991456/what-changes-made-to-a-computer-connected-to-a-domain-network-can-be-detected-by/991466#comment1367237_991456) of learning to like porridge if you decide to go ahead with this.

Comment: Ok, after reading the answers here I will not be fiddling around with network parameters. Leaving that aside, will installing some programs such as Firefox, Sumatra will get me in trouble? Most of the work is done on a java based webapp in IE 7.0, which is horrible, so want to replace that with FF.

Comment: @allrounder799 **You should not even attempt to install any software**. What if your PC gets a virus/trojan/keylogger and your bank loses all of it's password and customer data?. What do you think will happen to you when your bank customers lose all their money or have the account details leaked in the internet?

Comment: *don't touch anything*, There's a reason its the *first line* of my answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill: LOL if that would had to happen, it would have been by now. You really think the customer data can be hacked from a single computer or can be accessed by a run of a mill virus. Yes sophisticated data hacks happen, I know about them. But the bank and the country I live in don't have that much level of sophistication. My PC already has a bunch of viruses(the in-built incompetent Anti virus notifies me of them from time to time). Anyways thanks for cautioning me

Comment: "You really think the customer data can be hacked from a single computer or can be accessed by a run of a mill virus." erm. Thats *exactly* how it happens.